# How to pass LinQ Expressions from F# to C# code

Tags: c#, linq, f#

ReactiveUI has methods with signitures like

```
public static ReactiveUI.ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TRet> 
  ObservableToProperty<TObj, TRet>(
    this TObj This, 
    System.IObservable<TRet> observable, 
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TObj, TRet>> property, 
    TRet initialValue = null, 
    System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler = null
  )
```

In F# How would I construct an object like

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TObj, TRet>> property,
```

In C# I would do something like

```
this.ObservableAsPropertyHelper(
    observable,
    me => me.MyProperty
)
```

**EDIT**

I've tried

```ml
m.ObservableToProperty(this, value, fun me -> me.Property )
```

and

```ml
m.ObservableToProperty(this, 
            value, 
            new Linq.Expression.Expression(fun me -> me.Property )
```

but neither work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if the new F# 3 query expressions help you, but the old PowerPack (which still works great!) has an extension method `Expr.ToLinqExpression() : Expression`, to compile F# quotation expressions (i.e. `<@ fun me -> me.MyProperty @>`) into LINQ expressions.

**Edit:**
As Daniel had pointed out, [QuotationToLambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324072.aspx) does the works, for F# 3.

Comment: Tried that but I got a result of type "LinqExpression" instead of "LinqExpression<Func<object,propertyType>>"

Comment: @bradgonesurfing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx, specifically `Use the Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>) or Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression, ParameterExpression[]) method to create an Expression<TDelegate> object.` .

Comment: It looks like [`QuotationToLambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324072.aspx) is the way to do it in F# 3.0.