# Build a Linq expression from an F# function, to pass to C#

Tags: f#, windows-runtime, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

I am trying use the Lex.Db database in an F# project in a WinRT 8.1 app.

I am following [this tutorial](http://lexblog.azurewebsites.net/intro-to-lex-db/) for C#. I've successfuly added a reference to Lex.Db to an F# project and the simple calls in the tutorial translate to f# and compile (eg. `let db = new DbInstance("demo")`).

The problem is this C# code:

```
db.Map<Contact>().Key(i => i.Id)
```

-- Edit --

To save others from reading further, in F# 3.0 this is almost a non-problem. See kvb's comment below. The solution is:

`db.Map<Contact>().Key(fun i => i.Id)`

-- /Edit ---

The `Key` function expects an `Expression<Func<Contact,'a>>` and I am unable to build this in F#.

A very similar question appears in [How to pass LinQ Expressions from F# to C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874032/how-to-pass-linq-expressions-from-f-to-c-sharp-code). The recommended solution is to use `LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToLambdaExpression`.

I have tried this as follows:

```
 type Contact() =
    member val Id = 0 with get, set
    member val FirstName = "" with get, set

 let db = new DbInstance("Demo")

 let idExpr = LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToLambdaExpression
                        <@ fun (c : Contact) -> c.Id @>

 db.Map<Contact>().Key(idExpr) |> ignore    // <- Error
```

This produces a compiler error on `idExpr`:

*Type mismatch. Expecting a `Expression<Func<Contact,'a>>` but given a `Expression<(Contact -> int)>`. The type `'Func<Contact,'a>'` does not match the type `'Contact -> int'`.*

This question: [Expression<Func<T, bool>> from a F# func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134475/expressionfunct-bool-from-a-f-func) seems to address the problem directly, but the solution uses Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation, which I can't find in F# 3.0 for WinRT.

How do I turn `<@ fun (c : Contact) -> c.Id @>` into an `Expression<Func<Contact,'a>>`?

Comment: What happens if you just try `db.Map<Contact>.Key(fun i -> i.Id)` in F#?  F# 3.0 should apply a type-directed conversion when you pass a lambda where an `Expression` is expected.

Comment: That works #kvb, without any more ceremony! It compiles and runs. I've now got an F# View Model bound to a C# WinRT View, and the View Model reads from the database with just these few lines of code (almost..there are just a few more lines which are obvious from the tutorial and for exposing the View Model to data binding). Thankyou!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation` is in PowerPack, but as of v3.0 the functionality it provides is available in Core via `LeafExpressionConverter`. You can use the code in the question you linked, but change it to use `LeafExpressionConverter` for the translation part.

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers

let toLinq (expr : Expr<'a -> 'b>) =
  let linq = LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression expr
  let call = linq :?> MethodCallExpression
  let lambda = call.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression
  Expression.Lambda<Func<'a, 'b>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters)
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is correct and works. I can use it in my code as follows: `.Key(<@ fun (c : Contact) -> c.Id @> |> toLinq)`.

Comment: Readers, please note that @kvb's comment in my OP provides a simpler solution which works for my case. Daniel's solution will be helpful for building an expression with these various lower level API's, in F# 3.0.